# Keyboard and Mouse failing to respond

Tags: usb, kernel, keyboard, mouse

Edit: Problem randomly gone???

I have a workstation acting as a server running Ubuntu 18.04 for games and media and internal web pages at the moment, and everything was working fine until out of the blue the keyboard and mouse stopped working. They are the only USB devices in use to it may be all USB devices or just an input error. The keyboard is wired and the mouse is wireless, both work fine on my 18.04 desktop.

I was updating the kernel remotely the same day it broke, to I tried the kernel I was using when it worked, but it still didn't work. I also tried an  even newer kernel, with no success.

Thanks for any help!

Output of 'dkms status':

> nvidia, 390.87, 4.15.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed
>
> nvidia, 390.87, 4.15.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
>
> nvidia, 390.87, 4.18.11-041811-generic, x86_64: installed
>
> nvidia, 390.87, 4.18.16-041816-generic, x86_64: installed
>
> virtualbox, 5.2.10, 4.15.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed
>
> virtualbox, 5.2.10, 4.15.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed

It says these arrors in 'journalctl -xb' when booting:

> xhci_hcd 0000:08:00.0: Host halt failed, -110
>
> Oct 18 16:13:19 Aurora kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:08:00.0: can't setup: -110
>
> Oct 18 16:13:19 Aurora kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:08:00.0: USB bus 3 deregistered
>
> Oct 18 16:13:19 Aurora kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:08:00.0: init 0000:08:00.0 fail, -110
>
> Oct 18 16:13:19 Aurora kernel: xhci_hcd: probe of 0000:08:00.0 failed with error -110

Output of 'grep -i xhci /var/log/syslog*':

> /var/log/syslog:Oct 21 09:30:44 aurora kernel: [    0.416344] pci 0000:08:00.0: xHCI HW did not halt within 16000 usec status = 0x0
>
> /var/log/syslog:Oct 21 09:30:44 aurora kernel: [    1.280610] xhci_hcd 0000:08:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
>
> /var/log/syslog:Oct 21 09:30:44 aurora kernel: [    1.280618] xhci_hcd 0000:08:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
>
> /var/log/syslog:Oct 21 09:30:44 aurora kernel: [    1.320522] xhci_hcd 0000:08:00.0: Host halt failed, -110
>
> /var/log/syslog:Oct 21 09:30:44 aurora kernel: [    1.320523] xhci_hcd 0000:08:00.0: can't setup: -110
>
> /var/log/syslog:Oct 21 09:30:44 aurora kernel: [    1.320629] xhci_hcd 0000:08:00.0: USB bus 3 deregistered
>
> /var/log/syslog:Oct 21 09:30:44 aurora kernel: [    1.320659] xhci_hcd 0000:08:00.0: init 0000:08:00.0 fail, -110
>
> /var/log/syslog:Oct 21 09:30:44 aurora kernel: [    1.320782] xhci_hcd: probe of 0000:08:00.0 failed with error -110

Comment: Is this Ubuntu? What version? Are the keyboard/mouse plugged into a system USB port(s), or a PCI card, or USB hub?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04. Plugged straight into the front I/O, straight to the motherboard with no PCI card.

Comment: Use your BIOS settings for USB, and they should probably be set to `legacy`.

Comment: Already set to legacy.

Comment: What kernel are you running?

Comment: Same error and problem on 4.18.16, 4.18.11 and 4.15.36, Ihaven't tried any others.

Comment: Do you know what "Aurora kernel" is?

Comment: Yeah, Aurora is the name if the workstation

Comment: Does the USB work if you boot from a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: Haven't tested, but I'm 99% sure it's software related and not hardware.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to prove.

Comment: I figured that. The keyboard and mouse 100% work, I'm going to test the workstation tommorow again. I was more hoping someone could make sense if the error as I couldn't find any info on it.

Comment: Because there's so little information, we have to eliminate what we can. I know the keyboard/mouse work on another computer. But that's about all we know. Edit your question to show the output of `sudo debsums -s` and `dkms status` and `grep -i xhci /var/log/syslog*`.